# Json response from php script not working

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm building a form to upload images and other data and I want it to return json validation or success response via the ajax success function.

Problem is the php script seems to do some of the `if` statements, but then completely ignores the extensions validation statement and the file size validation.

I have a switch/case statement in the AJAX to handle the json response from the php script. the switch/case statement then shows the respective message and then fades out.

note: No errors were found in the console.

Thank you for any help.

AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $('.add_business_form').on('submit',(function(e) {  

        e.preventDefault();

        var formData = new FormData(this);


        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            data:formData,
            cache:false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            dataType: "json",
            success:function(response){

    switch(response.message){
      case 'logo_success': 
         logoSuccess();
      break;
      case 'file_is_not_image': 
        file_is_not_image();
      break;
      case 'No_file_selected': 
        No_file_selected();
      break;        

      case 'wrong_logo_extention':
        Wrong_extention();
      break;        
       case 'logo_too_big':
        logo_too_big();
      break;
       case 'unknown_error':
        unknown_error();
      break;
    }           

            },
            error: function(data){   


            }
        });
    }));

});
```

jQuery functions(to handle ajax response):

```
<script>
 function logoSuccess(){
 $('.response_success').fadeIn('fast').delay(10000).fadeOut('fast');    
$('.add_business_form')[0].reset();  
 }      
</script>   
<script>
 function file_is_not_image(){
 $('.file_is_not_image').fadeIn('fast').delay(10000).fadeOut('fast');    
 }      
</script>
<script>
 function No_file_selected(){
 $('.No_file_selected').fadeIn('fast').delay(10000).fadeOut('fast');         
 }      
</script>
<script>
 function logo_too_big(){
 $('.logo_too_big').fadeIn('fast').delay(10000).fadeOut('fast');         
 }      
</script>
<script>
 function unknown_error(){
 $('.unknown_error').fadeIn('fast').delay(10000).fadeOut('fast');        
 }      
</script>
```

PHP script

```
if(empty($_FILES['uploaded_img_preview']['name'])){
    $response["message"] = 'No_file_selected';
}else{

$imgFile = $_FILES['uploaded_img_preview']['name'];
$tmp_dir = $_FILES['uploaded_img_preview']['tmp_name'];
$imgSize = $_FILES['uploaded_img_preview']['size'];
$imgExt = strtolower(pathinfo($imgFile,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
$upload_dir = '../images/'; // upload directory


   // valid image extensions
   $valid_extensions = array('jpg','png','jpeg'); // valid extensions

   // rename uploading image
   $new_logo_name = rand(1000,1000000).".".$imgExt;

   // allow valid image file formats
   if(in_array($imgExt, $valid_extensions)){   
    // Check file size '5MB'
    if($imgSize < 500000)    {

    }
    else{
     $response["message"] = 'logo_too_big';
    }
   }
   else{
     $response["message"] = 'wrong_logo_extention';  
   }

    if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_dir,$upload_dir.$new_logo_name)){
     $response["message"] = 'logo_success'; 
    }else{
    $response["message"] = 'unknown_error'; 

    }
 }

echo json_encode($response);
exit();
```

Comment: use var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(response );  you cannot use json decode response directly.

Comment: it return true ? in_array($imgExt, $valid_extensions)

Comment: @MubasharIqbal but it's working on the others. such as the first `No_file_selected ` message.

Comment: @bxN5 Correction, when i var_dump the file extension ($imgExt) it returns NULL - meaning it has none, but the file gets uploaded successfully..... this is strange.

Comment: is request url correct? $(this).attr('action'). And can you check in browser console requested and return values?

Comment: @MubasharIqbal it wouldn't return the `No_file_selected ` message if it was requesting the wrong file. and as i said the php returns some values, but not others, such as size and extension errors. it just ignores them.

Comment: requesting wrong file and requesting no file are two different things. Your check in on when you don't select any file.

Comment: You have an error function but u not doing anything with it `error: function(data){`  log the errors on console and see what it say `error: function(data){ console.log(data)}`

Comment: It's selecting the correct file.

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile I tried uploading an image it returns: `Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "NULL↵{"message":"logo_success"}", status: 200, statusText: "OK"}`  p.s (the image was uploaded successfully)

Comment: show us your full js code

Comment: does this function exists in ur js `logoSuccess();`?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile that is all for the ajax call, there are only functions showing the response messages from the ajax call. example: `function logoSuccess(){
 $('.response_success').fadeIn('fast').delay(10000).fadeOut('fast'); 
$('.add_business_form')[0].reset();  
 }` you can see them all here, https://jsfiddle.net/nznd4kvu/

Comment: show the functions as well on your question, we might be missing something there

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile I added them to the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138244/discussion-between-masivuye-cokile-and-bob).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that the images are uploading when, the file size is large and also when the ext is wrong, is simple because, you are allowing your script to upload even if the errors exists, what you need is to have an error counter variable so that when the error occurs you increment the variable then only upload the image when the error counter is zero

here how :

```
<?php

$errors = "";//Count error
if (empty($_FILES['uploaded_img_preview']['name'])) {
    $response["message"] = 'No_file_selected';
} else {

    $imgFile    = $_FILES['uploaded_img_preview']['name'];
    $tmp_dir    = $_FILES['uploaded_img_preview']['tmp_name'];
    $imgSize    = $_FILES['uploaded_img_preview']['size'];
    $imgExt     = strtolower(pathinfo($imgFile, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    $upload_dir = '../images/'; // upload directory


    if ($imgExt != "jpg" && $imgExt != "png" && $imgExt != "jpeg" && $imgExt != "gif") {
        $response["message"] = 'wrong_logo_extention';

        $errors++; //increment
    }

    if ($imgSize > 500000) {

        $response["message"] = 'logo_too_big';
        $errors++; //increment
    }
    // rename uploading image
    $new_logo_name = rand(1000, 1000000) . "." . $imgExt;

    //upload only if there are no errors
    if ($errors <= 0) {

        if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_dir, $upload_dir . $new_logo_name)) {
            $response["message"] = 'logo_success';
        } else {
            $response["message"] = 'unknown_error';

        }

    }


}

echo json_encode($response);
exit();
?>
```